# How to let idlj compile idl files in ant

Tags: java, ant, sun, corba, idl

I've no idea how to compile my idl files with the sun-idl compiler (idlj) with the help of ant?

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[idldepend is an ant task verifying the dependencies of a CORBA/IDL file.](http://www.coderazzi.net/idldepend/)

**EDIT:** Added first line from their description.

Comment: jepp, I found it yesterday also. It's great.